# How to send POST to remote url?

Tags: vb6

How to send POST request to remote URL using VB6 ?

Comment: There are still people using VB6? :o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many ways to approach this. You can use WinInet API, WinHTTP API, WinHTTPRequest, or XMLHTTPRequest. I prefer the lower leveled Winsock, and you can read about it here:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=334645 . Winsock is a bit more complicated, and but a bit more powerful, in my opinion. If you want to do it simple and sweet, XML HTTP Request is the way to go, I use it in javascript too. Try something like:

```
Set myMSXML = New MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
myMSXML.open "POST", URL, True
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Firefox 3.6.4"
myMSXML.OnReadyStateChange = (Shown below)
myMSXML.send YourPostDataString
```

And the OnReadyStateChange function:

```
Dim HttpResponse As String

HttpResponse = myMSXML.responseText
```

If you find my code not working, or you're a bit confused, I'm sorry, I'm a bit rusty with VB nowadays. You can check out the official Microsoft documentation on XMLHTTPRequest here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: +1 Similar to the code posted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749491/soap-post-failure) which is a good sign.

Answer (score 5):

We can do this way also

```
Set myMSXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
myMSXML.open "POST", "http://....", False
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Firefox 3.6.4"
myMSXML.send "param1=value2&param2=value2"
MsgBox myMSXML.responseText
```

More references you can check [http://smartreferences.blogspot.in](http://smartreferences.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 1):

For my API worked only with "application/json" in "Content-Type" header.
Here is my code:

```
textJSON = "{ ""field1"":""value1"", ""field2"":""value2""}"
Set myMSXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
myMSXML.Open "POST", "http://...", False
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
myMSXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Firefox 3.6.4"
myMSXML.send textJSON
MsgBox myMSXML.responseText
```