# How to make available a .NET DLL with a service reference incorporated and use it from a VB6 application

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, dllimport, service-reference

Hi everybody and pardon me in advance if that question has already been covered but I couldn't find a precise answer before.

My situation is:
I have developed a library that has a service reference (because it calls a SOAP Web Service). 
The web config has some parameters set like proxy and so on.
I understand that the client has to know how to invoke this web service (address...) even though there's a proxy class between the client and the service reference.

So let's code an example:

```
public class Example
{
        public string Foo(string param1, string param2)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var service = new EU.ServiceTypeClient())
                {
                     // implementation here
                     var element = service.GetSomething(param1, param2)
                     ...
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This class has the service reference and the app.config

The client (console for example) has to know that configuration as well.
Therefore what you tipically do is to copy that file in the .NET solution or write codebehind.

```
var binding= new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_YourName";
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://blahblah");
var client= new ServiceTypeClient(basicHttpbinding,endpointAddress);
...
```

And if I use a proxy class, put in the middle, that recalls Example Class (let's say it has a property Example) and it's been instantiated by console app, **it has to own that configuration as well**.
The whole class hierarchy has to do it, otherwise an exception would have been thrown with the error message "Could not find endpoint element with name..."

Therefore, my question is:
because I have to make this DLL available to a **client developed in VB6**, how can it consume this?
Web service methods have signature with a couple of parameters, as you saw before.

- Is it possible to "inject" other parameters that describe the configuration file?
- Or is it possible to load a configuration file in VB6 and act like it were a .NET client?
- Or is it possible to write codebehind to do that?
  Any suggestions?

Request:

```
<xsd:element name="request">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="idCode" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Response:

```
<xsd:element name="response">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="idCode" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="requestDate" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element name="valid" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="address" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://blahblah/myservice"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
          contract="EU.myServicePortType" name="myServicePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Calling a SOAP web service only requires an [HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082101/how-to-send-post-to-remote-url), an XML string representing the post data, and to parse the XML result back into whatever object you need it to represent. It can be done from virtually any programming language. But you would need to post the details about what the expected request and response of the web service are for anyone to give you an example.

Comment: Just added extract from WSDL.
Ok sure, it can be done by HTTP Post but my problem is, how can it load the configuration has to be set to invoke service properly?
Thx in the meantime

Comment: If you are calling your managed Assembly from VB6 it presumably contains ComVisible types.  The configuration data will typically be read from MyAppName.exe.config, where MyAppName.exe is the calling VB6 application.

Comment: So you're basically saying that if I have an app.config like the one posted above, I just need the add the portion without header in the MyAppName.exe.config? Is that it?